# jQuery Validation - Remote function with additional data

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I am having issues with validating some data.

I want to check if someone has reviewed a company before by checking for the company_id and the logged in users account_number in my reviews table.

The code I currently has doesn't ever seem to find anything in the reviews table so doesn't warn people they can't submit another review.

Your help to get this working is much appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

Form

```
<form name="review" id="review" method="post" action="/db_processing/reviews/process-reviews.php">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($results['company_id']) ?>" name="company_id" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($_SESSION["ID"]) ?>" name="account_number" />
    <p class="cs-threequarter">
        <b>Comments:</b><br>
        <textarea name="comments" style="width:95%; height: 150px"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p class="cs-quarter">
        <b>Rating:</b>
            <span class="star-rating">
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
                <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
            </span>
    </p>
    <p><input class="cs-btn cs-red" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Review!"></p>
    <div class="cs-container"></div>
    <div class="cs-error-note" id="cs-error-note3"></div>
</form>

<script src="/js/validation/reviewval.js"></script>
```

jQuery Validation Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#review').validate({ 
        errorLabelContainer: "#cs-error-note3",
        wrapper: "li",
        ignore: "not:hidden",
        rules: {              
            comments: {
                required: true

            },
            account_number: {
                required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "/db_processing/reviews/check-account.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                             company_id: function() {
                             return $("#company_id").val();
                        }
                    },    }
            },
            rating: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {               
            comments: {
                required: "Please enter some comments."
            },
            account_number: {
                required: "You must be logged in to review.",
                remote: "You have already reviewed this company."
            },
            rating: {
                required: "Please select a rating."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                 form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

Check-account.php

```
<?php
    require('../../../private_html/db_connection/connection.php');
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);    
    if(isset($_POST['account_number'])) {
        $account_number = $_POST['account_number'];
        $compid = $_POST['company_id'];
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT account_number FROM reviews WHERE account_number =$account_number && company_id =$compid");
        $query->execute();
        $rows = $query->fetchAll();
        $total_rows = count($rows);
            if( $total_rows > 0 ){
                echo 'false';
            } else {
                echo 'true';
            }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think first you need to store user and company details in your review table when user first give review for some company.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, to confirm, both account_number & company_id are stored in the reviews table :)

Comment: Did you get any errors in your browser's console??

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't warn people they have submitted a review before. If I remove company_id=$compid from the check-account.php then it will warn people, but that's searching through all the reviews, not just the ones for that particular company.

Comment: You are not passing `account_number` in your post request.

Comment: @CyrilWalrus, you figured it out or still struggling with it?

Comment: Still struggling! Is it something so obvious? I've used the code you helped me with before but tried to customise it to this situation

Comment: @CyrilWalrus give me couple of mins and will make it work :)

Comment: @CyrilWalrus check this and let me know if you are looking for this http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/validation/index.php

Comment: @shehary it seems to be doing the job! Although, it might just be me but when I keep the session ID as 4 but change the company ID it still says I've reviewed the company, is this just an issue with it not being resent rather than it being based solely on the session ID?

Comment: @CyrilWalrus, the check is on `session ID` input which is `account_number` and in your original code `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($_SESSION["ID"]) ?>" name="account_number" />` so if it's value 4 will give error no matter what you put in `company id`

Comment: Thanks @Shehary, just tried it again with 8 in company ID and 2 in session ID and it didn't bring up the error message so seems to be working fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation code working fine, there is no problem expect unnecessary comma `,`. remove it, Not all browsers are very forgiving.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#review').validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#cs-error-note3",
        wrapper: "li"
        ignore: "not:hidden",
        rules: {              
            comments: 
                required: true
            },
            account_number: {
                required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "/db_processing/reviews/check-account.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                                company_id: function() {
                                return $("#company_id").val();
                            }
                        }, //<-----Remove this, it's unnecessary
                   }
            },
            rating: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {               
            comments: {
                required: "Please enter some comments."
            },
            account_number: {
                required: "You must be logged in to review.",
                remote: "You have already reviewed this company."
            },
            rating: {
                required: "Please select a rating."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                 form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

The problem is here, because of it validation and query both failing.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($results['company_id']) ?>" name="company_id" />
```

assign `id` to this input because you are fetching it's value with `id` selector in validation script here `return $("#company_id").val();` so it will be

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($results['company_id']) ?>" name="company_id" id="company_id" />
```

last in PHP

put quotes `'` around variables inside query, rest is all good and working.

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT account_number FROM reviews WHERE account_number = '$account_number' && company_id = '$compid'");
```

Comment: So the major thing that got it all working was was just the missing `id="company_id"`! Thanks for the full answer and best practise for keeping the code clean :)

Comment: you are most welcome, one workaround is when dealing with inputs and jQuery or JS always give id to inputs same as name (even you feel not necessary) inputs names  always unique so ids will also be unique and save you alot of time and these kind of problems.