# Jquery validation for emailId and phone number using remote method

Tags: jquery, validation, jsp, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate if input emailId and phone number exists or not using **jQuery Validation plugin(remote method)**. But i Don't know where i am going wrong. I tried using add method plugin but didn't work.can anyone help me where am i going wrong??

Here is the code.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

$('#myForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                emailId: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url:'verifyEmailOrPhone-'+$('#emailId').val()+'-'+$('#contactNumber').val(),
                        type:'GET',

                }
                },

                contactNumber:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 9,
                    maxlength: 10,
                    number: true,
                    remote: {
                        url:'verifyEmailOrPhone-'+$('#emailId').val()+'-'+$('#contactNumber').val(),
                        type:'GET',

                  }
                },

            },   
            messages:{
                emailId:{
                    remote: "emailId already taken"
                    },
                contactNumber:{
                    remote: "phone number exists"
                }   
                },

            submitHandler: function (form) { 
                // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }

        });
```

html

```
<div class="margin-top-10  contact-check has-feedback form-group" >
                       <input class="form-control input-lg" name="contactNumber" id="contactNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" size="25" type="text"  value="">
                   </div>
                   <div class="margin-top-10  email-check  form-group has-feedback" >
                       <input class="form-control input-lg" name="emailId" id="emailId" placeholder="Email" size="25"  value=""  type="text">
                   </div>
```

in console i'm getting **http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcExample/verifyEmailOrPhone--?emailId=bhagya%40gmail.com**

remote method is returning "emailId=bhagya%40gmail.com" in url where i need to return only input data.

Comment: can you post HTML and PHP, also you can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543598/jquery-validate-remote-check-if-email-already-exists/32548295#32548295 see if this helps and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946534/jquery-validation-remote-function-with-additional-data/32952869#32952869

Comment: Hi @Shehary i'm using in jsp.

Comment: *"but didn't work"* is not useful.  Please describe in detail exactly what is happening.  Is the ajax working?  What's the response from the server?

Answer (score 2):

1. You're sending a value of `true` instead of the value of the field

   ```
   data: {
       emailId: function() {
           return true; // <- ??
       }
   }
   ```
2. You don't need to use the `data` property at all since the value of the field is already sent by default.

Remove the `data` property entirely.

Of course this answer assumes your server-side script, which we cannot see, is constructed and working properly.

Comment: 1)i tried by putting the value of the field but didn't work

Comment: 2) removed the data property but doesn't seems to be working

Comment: @BhagyashreeO, *"doesn't seem to be working"* is not a useful problem description.  Are you looking at your console to observe the ajax response?  What about the server-side code?  You've only shown us half of the picture if you leave out the server-side script.

Comment: verifyEmailOrPhone--?contactNumber=8888888888   this  is what im getting in console.....

Comment: @BhagyashreeO, that means everything you've shown us is working as you designed it.  However, we would have no idea how your server-side script is designed to work or if it's broken.